# SubViews don't scroll but scroll bar appears scrolling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, subviews

I am creating scrollView programmatically, but for some reasons i can see the scrollView's scroll bar but the subViews aren't scrolling. Have added my codes below

```
//create a closure for scroll view
    let vcScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.dark_background

        return scrollView
    }()

//create closure for dark view
    let darkView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

//create a closure for offer label
    let offerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        return label
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true

        view.addSubview(vcScrollView)
        setUpViews()


    }

func setUpViews(){
        //scrollView
        vcScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        vcScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        vcScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        vcScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        vcScrollView.contentSize.height = 1500

        //Dark view
        vcScrollView.addSubview(darkView)
        darkView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        darkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        darkView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        darkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true

        //Offer Label
        darkView.addSubview(offerLabel)
        offerLabel.text = selectedOffer
        offerLabel.font = UIFont(name: String.defaultFontR, size: 29)
        offerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        offerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: darkView.topAnchor, constant: 95).isActive = true
        offerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: darkView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        offerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: darkView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    }
```

Have added the scroll view as a subView for the view too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide the constraint of dark view with scrollview.
Currently you are providing the constraint from the view. Like this-

```
darkView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

darkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcScollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    darkView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcScollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    darkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true
```

Also provide the bottom constraint so that scollview can take the content size properly.

Comment: I have already provided bottom constraints for my scroll view like vcScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: @chevi99 yes you provided but for scrollview you also need to provide leading, trailing, bottom , top to any subview of scrollview.  So that content size can be calculated.

Comment: if we take the darkView for instance I have already given leading, trailing, top and height which should replace the bottom constraint

Comment: @chevi99 yes you already given but from the view not from scroll view. If dark view is the subview of scrollview then constraint must be provided with the reference of scrollview. As you provide the constraint of offer label from its superview i.e. dark label.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your child of the scroll view is using the `view's` anchors.  Switch them to use the `scrollView's` anchors.  Also, instead of a trailing constraint, you can use a width constraint.  That will allow it to scroll up and down.

```
//Dark view
vcScrollView.addSubview(darkView)
darkView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
darkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
darkView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcScrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
darkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true
```

You will need to provide the bottom anchors of your child views if you want to include views under your darkView.